# Optimal way to learn DirectX?

Tags: directx, software-engineering

I am finding it very difficult to learn DirectX 11. The MSDN website is just full of unorganized information that doesn't seem to help at all. I am particularly looking for something that explains many if not all aspects of developing with DirectX 11. I have been searching for weeks and still come up empty. I have found some books but they don't really explain the fundamentals of the language at all. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi there.  This is a "how do I get started" question so it's not really appropriate for this site, and will likely be closed soon.  That aside: I feel your pain as the D3D11 documentation is - shall we say - not the best for this purpose.  Have you looked at Frank D Luna's book?

Comment: i've no idea what books you were looking at, one of the first things that pops in google is "Introduction to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11" and that's just about the best dx11 teaching resource you could ask for

Answer (score 2):

There is a series of DirectX 11 C++ tutorials here.

- [DirectX 11 Tutorials](http://rastertek.com/tutdx11.html)

I've found that this site isn't too bad.  I don't particularly like his programming style, but I suppose that's not really the point of his site.

Answer (score 1):

this dude dose it pretty good, exept that he wants cash for some topcis. http://directxtutorial.com/

but the basics and fundementals are free. he explains pretty good aswell.
there is some chapers on transformation, memory managment and directx stuff there. a good read!